# Find SQL table entry with a check on created at column

Tags: sql, database

I have a SQL database table that has one of the columns as "created_at". The column contains the date and time on which the entry was created.

The format of the column is as follows:

```
2019-07-14 11:36:15.000
```

How can I run a query which checks if this entry was created within the past 15 minutes from the current time?

Comment: Please tag RDBMS that you use. What you tried so far and what don't works?

Comment: ...because many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.

Answer (score 1):

In Standard SQL -- assuming that `created_at` has a `datetime`/`timestamp` type, you would use something like:

```
where created_at > current_timestamp - interval '15 minute'
```

That said, the date/time functions are notoriously database-dependent.  So the exact syntax might vary in your database.

Comment: The current_timestamp representation includes a timezone, use localtimestamp instead. And the interval literal should be `interval '15' minute`

Answer (score 0):

Solution in SQL Server will be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE created_at >= DATEADD(minute, -15, created_at );
```